# How to get the scale value of an html element using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering how I can get the scale value of an element?

I have tried `$(element).css('-webkit-transform');` which returns `matrix(scaleX,0,0,scaleY,0,0);` Is there a way of getting `scaleX` and `scaleY` only?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If it was specified by a matrix I guess you can't with a straightforward way, but you can easily parse the value:

```
var matrixRegex = /matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0,\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0\)/,
    matches = $(element).css('-webkit-transform').match(matrixRegex);
```

`matches[1]` will contain scaleX and `matches[2]` will contain scaleY. If it's possible that other transformations have also been applied, you'd need to slightly tweak the regex, because now it assumes that all other parameters are 0.

A way to just get the scale values might be to remove any transforms, measure the computed width/height of the element and then add them back and measure again. Then divide new/old values. Haven't tried it, but it might work. jQuery itself uses a similar approach for many measurements, it even has an undocumented `$.swap()` function just for this.

PS: You are using `-o-transform` `-moz-transform` and `-ms-transform` too, right?

Comment: +1 for making me realize that the game ain't worth the candle. I have to do something simpler before I go mad. ^_^

Comment: If other parameters aren't 0, you we can use `matrixRegex = /matrix\(\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*),\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*),\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*),\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*),\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*),\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*)\)/`

Answer (score 109):

The simplest solution to find out the scale factor between the document and an element is the following:

```
var element = document.querySelector('...');
var scaleX = element.getBoundingClientRect().width / element.offsetWidth;
```

This works because getBoundingClientRect returns the actual dimension while offsetWidth/Height is the unscaled size.

Comment: Great answer. It works fine on Chrome, and the MDN site suggests that it will work on IE9+ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Great answer. I didn't know getBoundingClientRect would get the actual scaled size.

Comment: In iOS Webview `element.getBoundingClientRect().width` does not return scaled width, just the normal width. I used `window.screen.width` instead.

Comment: Would this work if you rotated the element?

Comment: @AndyS no it wouldn't work in that case

Answer (score 9):

If you need to target webkit only (because it's for the iPhone, or iPad) the most reliable and fast way is using the native javascript webkit provides:

```
node = $("#yourid")[0];
var curTransform = new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(node).webkitTransform);
alert(curTransform.a); // curTransform is an object,
alert(curTransform.d); // a through f represent all values of the transformation matrix
```

You can view a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/umZHA/

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following:

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementID");
// returns matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)
var matrix = window.getComputedStyle(element).transform;
var matrixArray = matrix.replace("matrix(", "").split(",");
var scaleX = parseFloat(matrixArray[0]); // convert from string to number
var scaleY = parseFloat(matrixArray[3]);
// bonus round - gets translate values
var translateX = parseFloat(matrixArray[4]); 
var translateY = parseFloat(matrixArray[5]); // parseFloat ignores ")"
```

Comment: I believe you have an extra "matrix" in line 3. Should be var matrixArray = matrix.replace("matrix(", "").split(",");

Answer (score 3):

A more robust and generic way to get the scale :

```js
const { width, height } = element.getBoundingClientRect()
const scale = { x : element.offsetWidth / width, y : element.offsetHeight / height }
```

It compares the visual dimensions with the non-scaled dimensions. So it will work even with nested scaled elements.

Comment: Interesting. It's worth mentioning that, to return the same value used as the scale, it'd be interesting to invert the division. `const scale = { x : width / element.offsetWidth, y : element / node.offsetHeight }`.

Comment: Interesting.  When I calculate these values for an image with height and width constrained by max-height and max-width (to fit the whole image on the screen with preserved aspect ratio), the offset* numbers and the GetBoundingClientRect are just about the same numbers, the latter being the next larger integer.  That doesn't tell me how much the image is scaled, which I would love to know!

Comment: In your case @Victoria you should not use offsetWidth/offsetHeight but [naturalWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) and [naturalHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight).

Answer (score 2):

Too late for the OP but might be useful in the future. There is a straightforward way to do it using splits:

```
function getTransformValue(element,property){       
        var values = element[0].style.webkitTransform.split(")");
        for (var key in values){
            var val = values[key];              
            var prop = val.split("(");          
            if (prop[0].trim() == property)
                return prop[1];
        }                   
        return false;           
    }
```

This is webkit specific, but can easily be extended for more browsers modifying the fist line.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
element.style.transform.match(/scale\(([1-9\.])\)/)[1]
```