# How to replace the deprecated "svgElement.offsetWidth/height" on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

[Chrome Platfrom](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784) announces that it will deprecate offsetWidth soon. And it suggests developers to use getBoundingClientRect() instead.

But [when there is a scale](https://jsfiddle.net/520g8fmw/), they are different.

```
<div id="wrap"  style="transform: scale(2); width:300;height:300;">
   <svg id="real" style="border:red 10px solid;" >
     <rect/>
   </svg>
</div>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById("real");
var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect(); 
console.log(e.offsetWidth);  //320
console.log(e.clientWidth);  //300
console.log(rect.width);     //640   
</script>
```

In [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545593/how-to-get-the-scale-of-a-svgelement), I tried to find an official API to get the scale but failed.

How to replace the deprecated "svgElement.offsetWidth/height/parent" on Chrome when there is a scale?

One way I can think is to get the border width and add it to clientWidth. Is there a api to get svg border? Using e.style.borderRightWidth and doing the string parsing doesn't look nice.

Any answer or comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to remove to `transform` for all ancestors, calcualte the client rect, and then restore the transform of the ancestors:

```
function getOffsetWidth(elm) {
  var cur, i;
  var saveTransforms = [];

  i = 0;
  cur = elm;
  //set the transform to '' for all ancestors
  while (cur) {
    if (cur.style) {
      saveTransforms[i] = cur.style.transform;
      cur.style.transform = '';
    }
    i++;
    cur = cur.parentNode;
  }
  var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect();

  i = 0;
  cur = elm;


  //restore the transform for all ancestors
  while (cur) {
    if (cur.style) {
      cur.style.transform = saveTransforms[i];
    }
    i++;
    cur = cur.parentNode;
  }


  return rect.width;
}
```

Here the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/520g8fmw/3/)