# Read css scale value using JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this div

```
<div style="transform: scale(2,3)"></div>
```

How do I get the

```
transform: scale(x,y)
```

of an element using JS or jQuery.

```
$('#id').css('transform')
```

gives me the matrix but i need the actual scale values from my element. Or if I cannot get the scale directly then what is the calculation to convert the matrix() to scale if I have

```
var mt = matrix(....); how do I then convert mt[0] and mt[3] to actual scale values.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Get the scale value of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603615/get-the-scale-value-of-an-element):

```js
var matrixRegex = /matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0,\s*(-?\d*\.?\d+),\s*0,\s*0\)/;
var matches = $('#id').css('transform').match(matrixRegex);
console.log(matches)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id" style="transform: scale(2,3)"></div>
```

That snippet will return an array with the original matrix, and then indexes 2 and 3 contain X and Y values, respectively. Credit to Lea Verou

Answer (score 3):

```js
var m = $('#id').css('transform');
var mt = m.substring(m.indexOf('(') + 1, m.indexOf(')')).split(',');
// or else: var mt = m.substring(7, m.length - 1).split(',');
console.log(mt[0], mt[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='id' style="transform: scale(2,3)"></div>
```

You can put a plus sign in front of the array elements to ensure they are treated as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container" style="transform: scale(2,3)"></div>
```

and then

```
var vals = $('#container').css('transform').replace(/\(|\)|scale/g,'').split(',')
```

Now, you have the scale values in `vals` as string, just parse `parseFloat(vals[0])` and `parseFloat(vals[1])` to number to get the value of `x` and `y`

Answer (score -2):

Try this HTML

```
<div id="container" style="transform: scale(2,3)"></div>
```

Try this JS

```
console.log($('#container').attr('style'))
```