# How to retrieve the real size of a div after transform scale is applied?

Tags: javascript, css

After I applied a `transform: scale(n)` to a div, the `width` and `height` I obtain via javascript stay the same.

The following illustrates the setup.

```js
console.log($('.parent1').width())
console.log('parent1 w ' + $('.parent1 .container').width())
console.log('parent1 h ' + $('.parent1 .container').height())

$('.parent2').css('transform', 'scale(1.5)')
console.log('parent2 w ' + $('.parent2 .container').width())
console.log('parent2 h ' + $('.parent2 .container').height())
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
}

.parent1 {
  height: 100px;
}

.parent2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent parent1">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent parent2">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the print out in the console, the width and height of the second container is the same as the first one. However for a user the second container is actually larger.

How can I obtain the actual size of `$('.parent2 .container')`?

The scale is applied from another process and the scale factor is not accessible to me.

Comment: Multiply size with scale?

Comment: The scale factor is not available to me.

Comment: You can apparently use `element.getBoundingClientRect()` (found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603615/get-the-scale-value-of-an-element)

Comment: @ChrisG you can, it's fast, and it has a great browser support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```js
console.log($('.parent1').width())
console.log('parent1 w ' + $('.parent1 .container').width())
console.log('parent1 h ' + $('.parent1 .container').height())

$('.parent2').css('transform', 'scale(1.5)')
console.log('parent2 w ' + $(".parent2 .container")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width)
console.log('parent2 w ' + $(".parent2  .container")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height)
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
}

.parent1 {
  height: 100px;
}

.parent2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  height:50%;
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent parent1">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent parent2">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the scaled width/height is not 1.5x the original width/height?